Counting by recursion
I want to understand how to solve counting problems by using "recursive counting". I did look at two examples. But I do not understand how the final recursion came about. Here are the examples:

Example 1:
Consider a $2 \times n$ rectangle. How many ways are there to fill in this rectanlge with $2 \times 1$ rectangles.
Let $f(n)$ denote the number of combinations for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
One can notice that at the end of the rectangle there can be either

one vertical $2 \times 1$ rectangle or
two horizintal $2 \times 1$ rectangles

In the first case, if we remove the vertical $2 \times 1$ rectangle we are left with a $2 \times (n-1)$.
In the second case, if we remove the two horizontal rectangles $2 \times 1$, we are left with a $2 \times (n-2)$ rectangle.
Thus we get the recursion $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$.

Example 2: (triangulation of n-gon):
In how many ways can we triangulate a $n$-gon?
Consider a $n$-gon.
We can split the n-gon into three parts. A left $k$-gon, a triangulation in the "middle" and a $(n-k+1)$-gon on the right side.
Thus we can write $f(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)f(n-k+1)$.

In the first example, we get $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ by spliting the problem into two parts.
But in the second example we get $f(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)f(n-k+1)$ by doing the same.
I do not understand how we get to both formulas.
Looking at the frist example, we consider two possible cases, then we write the amount of combinations as the sum of the "previous states".
But by that logic shouldn't the recursion in example 2 be $f(n)=f(k)+f(n-k+1)$?

@MauroALLEGRANZA I did a drawing for both examples. But I do not get by we one we just add and in the next we have a sum of multiplications.

For your second example, $k$ can vary so you need to sum across the possibilities (though it is from $2$ to $n-1$ rather than to $n$).  This also mean you need to know what a $2$-gon is and that there is $1$ way to triangulate it with $0$ triangles.
As an illustration, consider a hexagon, and the possible triangles involving a particular edge, shown in red below, leaving a dark blue $k$-gon to one side and a light blue $n-k+1$-gon on the other.

This tells you $f(6)=f(2)f(5) +f(3)f(4)+f(4)f(3)+f(5)f(2)$ and illustrates $f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n-1} f(k)f(n-k+1)$. You have a sum of products.
Since $f(2)=1$, $f(3)=f(2)f(2)=1$, $f(4)=f(2)f(3)+f(3)f(2)=2$, and $f(5)=f(2)f(4)+f(3)f(3)+f(4)f(2)=5$, this means you can find $f(6)=14$.  Some people may spot the appearance of Catalan numbers.
